# How do you calculate feature branch changes in Git?

Tags: git

I would like to identify all the sum of all code changes made on a git feature branch.

Take the example below, how would you determine the real changes written for feature XYZ?   D and G represent the only real changes.  I thought I might be able to do this by measuring the difference between A and G but merge F inflates G with code that has nothing to do with feature XYZ.

I'm thinking I'll have to traverse this myself (I'd use GithPython) and sum the changes from A->D and F->G.  Are there flaws to this strategy?  Are there better ways?

```
                 D --- F -- G           featureXYZ_branch
                /     /      \
    HISTORY--- A -- B -- C -- D ----    master
```

Comment: So basically, you want to *visually see* `git diff A G` excluding the lines from `git diff B F`?

Comment: @Matten - yes.  And does it make sense why?  I'm trying to see the unique work that was done on the feature branch.

Answer (score 2):

You can see your changes between those two branches by following way:

```
git diff featureXYZ_branch master
  OR
git diff remotes/origin/featureXYZ_branch remotes/origin/master
```